# Start ten thousands of Quartz jobs

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cron

I'm new in Quartz and I need to start ten thousands of jobs each 10 seconds.

is that possible? If yes, how can I do that? is there a specific configuration or any recommendation?

**EDIT:**

I'm providing more information about my issue:

My platform is targeting about 1000 users. Each user can have at most 10 dashboards. Each dashboard is related to a text file hosted on a separate server. These text files can be updated by other applications that I may not control. Users can configure the update frequency of their dashboards. Minimum allowed value is 10 seconds.

To resolve this issue, I think that we should create one job/thread/process/worker (call it what ever you want :) ) per dashboard and configure the "job" to read the related text file every x seconds and update the dashboard if changes detected.

So, in worst case, my solution should support 10000 "jobs" every 10 seconds.

The technical environment is:

- Ubuntu 14.04 server edition
- RAM: 6G RAM
- CPU: 4x2 Ghz
- JavaEE, Spring and cxf

I already tried Java Quartz scheduler, but I had some problems like HeapSpace and heaviness when calling web services. This is My Quartz configuration:

Create Job:

```
job = JobBuilder.newJob(WidgetGraphJob.class)
                .withIdentity("jobName"), "groupName").requestRecovery(true).build()
```

Create trigger:

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("triggerName", "groupNmae").startNow() .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(10).repeatForever()).build();
```

Start job:

```
 Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
 scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Quartz configuration:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#============================================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: MyScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 100
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class: org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Is there any better solution for this issue? Can I consider the linux crontab as a possible solution (I should manage the seconds parts separately since crontab doesn't support seconds) or quartz is enough and I just need to enhance my hardware configuration or choose another JobStore configuration ?

Many thanks for your help. Best regards

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: create jobs and define cron expression for them, but tens of thousands for every 10 secs seems too much.

Comment: The best way would be to get 1,000 computers, each running 10 jobs every 10 seconds.

Comment: As I know, Quartz can be used to create simple or complex schedules for executing tens, hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands of jobs. But I don't know the good configuration to do that. For Exemple we can configure at most 100 per Scheduler instance using RAMJobStore, but I can see some heapspace problem, losing job reference, heaviness after running only 100 jobs. I'm using Server with 4G RAM and 4*2GHz

Comment: This is an X Y problem.  You have problem X, and you think Y will solve it, but instead of asking about X, you're asking how to make your solution Y work.  Ask us about X instead; we can probably provide a better solution than the one you're proposing.